# Codeigniter htaccess adds an extra forward slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

This is my current .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

My config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/argh/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And when I click, for example, on the about us link it looks like this:

```
http://localhost/argh//about
```

(2 forward slashes between argh and about)

Any suggestion? : )

EDIT:

Not sure, but this looks like a Codeigniter issue, because the function:

```
function site_url($uri = '')
{
    if ($uri == '')
    {
        return $this->slash_item('base_url').$this->item('index_page');
    }

    if ($this->item('enable_query_strings') == FALSE)
    {
        $suffix = ($this->item('url_suffix') == FALSE) ? '' : $this->item('url_suffix');
        return $this->slash_item('base_url').$this->slash_item('index_page').$this->_uri_string($uri).$suffix;
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->slash_item('base_url').$this->item('index_page').'?'.$this->_uri_string($uri);
    }
}
```

More precisely here:

```
return $this->slash_item('base_url').$this->item('index_page');
```

returns the base_url when:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

That's why the previous example ends like this:

```
http://localhost/argh//about
```

Comment: did you tried to remove the last slash from base URL and adding rewrite base to your htaccess like /argh

Comment: the base URL should be local host and rewrite base argh

Comment: As your codeigniter install is inside a directory `argh` within your webroot, you will need to reflect this in your htaccess. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /argh/index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: Jeemusu.. didn't work. Please notice my edit part of the post and feel free to comment.

Answer (score 2):

Check you aren't writing:

```
base_url().'/about'
```

in your queries - base_url() will use the / from your config file

also, remove the second . from this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

to read:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: My link is using the site_url() function:
`<a href="<?php echo site_url() . '/about'; ?>">About Us</a>`

And 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] `
didn't work.

Comment: site_url()  is the same - it already has the / at the end.

    echo site_url();

Comment: Make it become base_url()."/about', and RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1

Answer (score 0):

Use this in .htacces file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Use this for base url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/argh';
```

and use path as form action

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>Your_Controller_Name">;
```

for href use this

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("Controller_Name/Action_name"); ?>">About Us</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this in system -> url_helper.php file

```
rtrim($CI->config->site_url($uri),'/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just incase someone faces the same problem in the future:

I had the same problem because of the way i was redirecting, for example after successful login I used **`header("Location:".site_url()."/admin/home");`** even after removing **`index.php`** from **`$config['index_page']=''`** i kept getting **`http://example.com//admin/home`**

Solution:
Use the **`redirect()`** function that CI provides and not **`header('');`**
i.e

Change: **`header("Location:".site_url()."/admin/home");`** to **`redirect('/admin/home')`**

Answer (score 0):

this work

`<a href="<?php echo site_url('Controller_Name') ?>" </a> change to    <a href="#" onclick="window.location='<?php echo site_url('Controller_Name'); ?>'"></a>`